# Exporting shp in geodatabase using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase

I have different data layers and I want to create a function that takes the name of the region as a parameter and generate a database with the different layers of the region in it.
I made this code but when executing it doesn't produce anything. I have a problem with the selection by attribute of the script.
I used the documentation of ArcGIS Pro but it does not take into account the selection.

Do you have any idea where the error could come from or any suggestions to improve my script?

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Lenovo P53s\OneDrive\Bureau\data"

arcpy.management.CreateFileGDB("database", "base")

# récupération des données
departements = r"Data-20220403\DEPARTEMENT.shp"
regions = r"Data-20220403\REGION.shp"
rivers= r"riviere\riviere\riviere.shp"
roads= r"route\route\route.shp" 
def selection(param):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(regions , ["NOM_REG", "INSEE_REG"]) as cursor:
        for name in cursor:
            if name[0] == param:
                # select layer with param 
                region_selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(regions, "NEW_SELECTION", "INSEE_REG = 'param'")

                # select department of selected region
                departements_selection = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(departements, "WITHIN", region_selection, None, "SUBSET_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")

                arcpy.analysis.Clip(routes, region_selection, r"database\base.gdb\routes_selection", None)

                arcpy.analysis.Clip(rivieres, region_selection, r"database\base.gdb\rivieres_selection", None)

            elif name[0].lower() == 'all':
                arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(departements, r'database\base.gdb')
                arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(rivieres, r'database\base.gdb')
                arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(routes, r'database\base.gdb')
            else:
                print("Paramètre invalid")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause in the select by attribute is not using the param variable but is looking for the text string param.
Try coding your select by attribute as two parts.

```
where_clause = "INSEE_REG = '{0}'".format(param)
region_selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(regions, "NEW_SELECTION",where_clause)
```